# Cannot Edit in Excel From Sharepoint Online

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, office365, sharepoint

First of all, I am working within Office 365 ProPlus and SharePoint online from the Office 365 portal.
I can navigate through sharepoint to an excel document and open it within Excel Online.
However when I try to edit this within Excel in Office365 ProPlus, SharePoint online says the document has been opened in Excel and I can close the browser window, however this is not the case as I see no excel document opening.

Is this an issue with Office365 or SharePoint online?

The only things I've managed to try is a repair on Office and resetting Internet Explorer settings. Those were the only things I could see effecting this interaction.

Also reading articles on the web only brought up compatibility issues with browsers (chrome and Firefox), earlier versions of office (2016 and 2010 and so on) and earlier versions of sharepoint (sharepoint 2013). These all are irrelevant as I have Internet Explorer and Office365 and sharepoint online (which I assume are fully compatible versions).

Can anyone tell me what is causing this issue?

Comment: We are also in O365 Enterprise with SharePoint online. I have told my team to navigate to the file and then, from it's library level, choose to open in Excel or Excel online - rather than opening in the web app and then using the link to open in Excel. Our experience has been that opening it from the web app locks it as a read only file so that it cannot be saved directly to SharePoint.

Comment: @hudsonsedge the issue you describe here does not seem related to my issue as I cant open the document in local Excel on the machine regardless of where I try in SharePoint online. The window appears telling me it has opened in Excel (Not Excel online) but the window does not appear.